Can someone help me understand why this leetcode solution is not accepted for all cases?
I am just learning coding and I am solving what should be easy problems but I don't understand in this case why this code fails? I put it into VS code and it returns what I think is the correct answer (which is "the index of the beginning of the substring"), but my code fails on the 15th test, which uses "mississippi" compared with "issip". I actually don't know what the issue is because it compiles fine when I enter those as input in VS code.
Here is the problem statement/link:

Find the Index of the First Occurrence in a String

Given two strings needle and haystack, return the index of the first occurrence of needle in haystack, or -1 if needle is not part of haystack.
Example 1:
Input: haystack = "sadbutsad", needle = "sad"
Output: 0
Explanation: "sad" occurs at index 0 and 6.
The first occurrence is at index 0, so we return 0.
Example 2:
Input: haystack = "leetcode", needle = "leeto"
Output: -1
Explanation: "leeto" did not occur in "leetcode", so we return -1.
MY CODE
`
public int StrStr(string haystack, string needle)
{
    if (needle == haystack)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (needle.Count() > haystack.Count())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int currentIndex = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int target = needle.Count();
    int seeIfAtTarget = 0;
    string tempString = needle;

    //goes through the main word
    foreach (char letterInMainWord in haystack)
    {   //if the letter is the same as the first letter of the comparison
        if (letterInMainWord == needle[0])
        {
            currentIndex = i;
            //loops through the letters in the compared word
            foreach (char letter in tempString)
            {   //adds one to seeIfAtTarget, and we will check to see if that meets the target
                if (letter == haystack[currentIndex])
                {
                    seeIfAtTarget++;
                    currentIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    seeIfAtTarget = 0;
                    break;
                }
                if (seeIfAtTarget == target)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}

`
I tried using breakpoint debugging and the watch lists in VS and I also tried using AI

When you use the inputs "mississippi"/"issip", what result do you get and what result does the site expect you to get? And the funny thing is that you can replace all your function code with return haystack.IndexOf(needle);

When I use those inputs in VS I get "4" as the return.
On the website I get an outofbounds exception that I assume must happen here
"
if (seeIfAtTarget == target)
{
return i;
}
"
From leetcode
Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At Solution.StrStr(String haystack, String needle)
At DriverSolution.Helper(String param_1, String param_2)
At Driver.Main(String[] args)
Also I can't seem to figure out how to get these comments to format either...

It also says this I noticed, which is weird because earlier it was compiling and saying it was working
Line 18: Char 19: error CS0176: Member 'Solution.StrStr(string, string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead (in Driver.cs)

You probably need to make the method static. public static int StrStr(string haystack, string needle)

Thank you for the help - It still does not compile that way and says the same thing.

Hello I solved this problem.
It was encountering an outofbounds exception because I needed to check for the condition that if(currentIndex > (haystack.Length - target)), then I can return -1 because the string no longer has enough room to fit. This game me the green light on my code (I am sure it can still be optimized ofc).
My answer:
public class Solution {
    public int StrStr(string haystack, string needle)
    {
        if (needle == haystack)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (needle.Count() > haystack.Count())
        {
            return -1;
        }

        int currentIndex = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int target = needle.Count();
        int seeIfAtTarget = 0;

        //goes through the main word
        foreach (char letterInMainWord in haystack)
        {   //if the letter is the same as the first letter of the comparison
            if (letterInMainWord == needle[0])
            {
                currentIndex = i;
                if(currentIndex > (haystack.Length - target))
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                //loops through the letters in the compared word
                foreach (char letter in needle)
                {   //adds one to seeIfAtTarget, and we will check to see if that meets the target
                    if (letter == haystack[currentIndex])
                    {
                        seeIfAtTarget++;
                        currentIndex++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        seeIfAtTarget = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (seeIfAtTarget == target)
                    {
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

